# Uneven Data Replication on Hadoop DataNodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am working to create a small Hadoop cluster on my network.  I have 1 NameNode and 2 DataNodes:

```
garage => NameNode
garage2 => DataNode
garage3 => DataNode
```

On the NameNode, I formatted hdfs using:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

I then created the user directories:

```
hadoop dfs -mkdir /user
hadoop dfs -mkdir /user/erik
hadoop dfs -mkdir movielens
```

I then uploaded a few files to test it out:

```
hadoop dfs -put * movielens
```

My expectation was that both datanodes would contain full copies of the data since my replication factor is set to 2 in hdfs-site.xml (Same config file on all 3 nodes):

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.replication</name>
   <value>2</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:/mnt/data/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/mnt/data/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
   <value>false</value>
 </property>
```

However, I am seeing an uneven distribution of data files in the hdfs folders on disk:

garage2 (DataNode):

```
erik@garage2:/mnt/data/hdfs$ du -h
4.0K    ./datanode/current/BP-152062109-192.168.0.100-1475633473579/tmp
4.0K    ./datanode/current/BP-152062109-192.168.0.100-1475633473579/current/rbw
619M    ./datanode/current/BP-152062109-192.168.0.100-1475633473579/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0
619M    ./datanode/current/BP-152062109-192.168.0.100-1475633473579/current/finalized/subdir0
619M    ./datanode/current/BP-152062109-192.168.0.100-1475633473579/current/finalized
619M    ./datanode/current/BP-152062109-192.168.0.100-1475633473579/current
619M    ./datanode/current/BP-152062109-192.168.0.100-1475633473579
619M    ./datanode/current
619M    ./datanode
619M    .
```

And from garage3 (DataNode):

```
erik@garage3:/mnt/data/hdfs$ du -h
4.0K    ./datanode
8.0K    .
```

Am I missing something in my configuration that will even this distribution/data replication out?

Comment: It looks like garage3 has either not had the datanode started or the datanode failed on startup or it failed to connect to the namenode. This is because it has not created the datanode/current/BP... directory. Check the log file in /var/log/hadoop-hdfs for errors on that datanode to see if there are any clues.

Comment: That was exactly it!  For some reason there was a problem with encoding in one of the files so I just re-deployed the Hadoop environment and it seems to be working as expected now.  Thanks for your help!  Now, how do I mark this as answered?